# How to create one output file for each file passed to a loop in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a file that I pass to a bash command that will create an output in a loop like so:

```
for file in /file/list/*
do
    command
done
```

I wish to save the output that would have gone to standard out of each loop to a text file in my working directory. Currently I am trying this:

```
for file in /file/list/*
do
    command | tee "$file_command output.txt"
done
```

What I expect to see are new files created in my current directory titled file1.txt_commandoutput.txt, file2.txt_commandoutput.txt, etc. The output of the command should be saved as a different file for each file. However I get only one file created and it's called ".txt" and can't be opened by any standard software on Mac. I am new to bash scripting, so help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `for each file in ...` is improper `bash` syntax...

Comment: Typing error, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in your script.

First, the wrong parameter/variable is expanded (`file_command` instead of `file`) because it's followed by a character that can be interpreted as part of the name (the underscore, `_`). To fix it, **enclose the parameter name in braces**, like this: `${file}_command` (see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in `bash` manual).

Second, even with fixed variable name expansion, the file won't be created in your working directory, because the `file` holds an absolute pathname (`/file/list/name`). To fix it, you'll have to **strip the directory** from the pathname. You can do that with either `basename` command, or even better with a modified shell parameter expansion that will strip the longest matching prefix, like this: `${file##*/}` (again, see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), section on `${parameter##word}`).

All put together, your script now looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /file/list/*
do
    command | tee "${file##*/}_command output.txt"
done
```

Also, to just save the command output to a file, without printing it in terminal, you can use a simple [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections), instead of `tee`, like this: `command > "${file##*/}_com..."`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the variable name you're using:

`"$file_command_output.txt"` looks for a variable named `file_command_output` (the dot cannot be in the variable name, but the alphanumerical characters and the underscore all can).

What you're looking for is `"${file}_command_output.txt"` to make the variable name more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware of `xargs`, try this:

```
$ ls
file
$ cat > file
one
two
three
$ while read this; do touch $this; done < ./file
$ ls
file  one  three  two
```