# How to prevent file overwriting in bash script?

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to automate a process which take a file type **NIFTI**, preprocess it, and places the new processed file in an output folder.

```
deepbrain-extractor -i <input-dir> -o <output-dir>
```

I wrote this bash script to automate this process for all files in a directory:

```
for file in path/*.nii
do
    deepbrain-extractor -i $file -o path/newfiles
done
```

The problem is every time the code runs, it overwrites the old files (since all automatically get the same name). Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: In this case, the shell has no control, as it is `deepbrain-extractor` that defines what happens to `path/newfiles`.

Comment: Copy the files into a backup directory, run deepbrain-extractor, then move them back (with changed names, maybe <file>-old.nii

Comment: Do you want `path/newfiles` to be different for each input file? What behavior do you _want_ to happen, instead of the behavior you actually get?

Comment: If what you want is to create an output file name based on the input name, then it might be something like `deepbrain-extractor -i "$file" -o "${file%.nii}.out"` (and this question would be a duplicate of ones already in our knowledge base).

Comment: [How to create one output file for each file passed to a loop in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244467/how-to-create-one-output-file-for-each-file-passed-to-a-loop-in-bash) is one such duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the suggestions and comments!
seems like using this code gives me what I want.

```
deepbrain-extractor -i "$file" -o "${file%.nii}.out"
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

A common way to get a unique file name is to use the current date and time.
You can combine this with the input file name to ensure that output files are never overwritten.

```sh
if [ ! -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$FILE does not exist."
    for file in path/*.nii
    do
    deepbrain-extractor -i $file -o path/newfiles_${file##*/}_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    done
fi
```

so the output directory has a name like `newfiles_input_2020-11-13_12-34-56`

Also see [How to create one output file for each file passed to a loop in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244467/how-to-create-one-output-file-for-each-file-passed-to-a-loop-in-bash)

Comment: Duplicative questions should be closed, not answered. See the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).